# Kotlin Standard Functions Unresolved Reference Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

Suddenly all of the projects in Android Studio are getting this unresolved reference for kotlin standard functions like `.let` , `.apply` , `listOf` & `mutableListOf` and also missing coroutine scope functions like `.launch`

[image]

Android Studio Version : 2020.3.1

**Things I've tried**

- Created a new project
- Deleted App build folder & library build folder
- Cleaned Project , Rebuild Project & Invalidate Caches & Restart
- Deleted .idea folder and rebuilt project

> App builds and runs fine on emulator , just the IDE gives this error in every project

Comment: This is a Gradle issue I think, make sure you have this dependency in app module implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'. This library provides all the extensions, coroutines lambdas, etc.

Comment: I have it in all the projects & its is giving the same error in all the projects

Comment: App builds and runs fine on emulator but this error appears in Android Studio , that's how I know its not a bug related to my build configuration and my code

Comment: maybe I should just uninstall Android Studio and reinstall it

Comment: Its working fine in Bumblebee version of the Android Studio , latest canary build which confirms that This is an IDE issue

Comment: Then you should try reinstalling Android Studio and if the issue don't get resolved, report it to Google.

Comment: Do you see any error icon in the Bottom Right Corner of the Android Studio along with little emojis?

Comment: nope ! no icon in the bottom right corner , I have seen that error , that happened yesterday , where Android Studio was prompting me to press the icon in the bottom right corner to report it , even though I still did not see an icon

Comment: Hello @WaqasTahir, I am having the same issue. Even though I deleted ".gradle", ".idea", "SDK" and tried to reinstall Android studio but still have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: so I use Android Studio bumblebee instead of arctic fox

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by changing the Gradle version.

change the gradle-wrapper.properties